# Understanding Gelfand–Raikov theorem

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, locally-compact-groups

The context is unitary representations of locally compact topological groups.

> **Theorem (Gelfand–Raikov)**. Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group. Then $G$ is separated by its irreducible representations, i.e., for any $x,y\in G$, $x\neq y$, there is an irreducible representation $\rho:G\to U(\mathcal{H})$ such that $\rho(x)\neq\rho(y)$.

I learned this theorem and its proof from *A Course in Abstract Harmonic Analysis* by G. B. Folland. Then I read the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Raikov_theorem) and saw the following remark concerning this theorem:

> It states that a locally compact group is completely determined by its (possibly infinite dimensional) unitary representations.

#### Questions

1. How do I understand this remark? What is meant by "completely determined"? In what sense?
2. More generally, how do I understand the role of this theorem in the theory? Why do we care about whether the irreducible representations separate points?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the article, for an irreducible representation $\pi: G \to U(H)$ (necessarily finite dimensional), we can define matrix elements with respect to some orthonormal basis of $H$ as $$\pi_{ij}(g) = \langle e_i, \pi(g) e_j \rangle.$$
Let $\mathcal{E}_\pi$ be the linear span of the matrix elements and let $\mathcal{E}$ be the linear span of $\cup_{[\pi]} \mathcal{E}_\pi$ where in the union we choose a representative from each unitary equivalence class of irreducible representations of $G$. It is a big part of the [Peter-Weyl theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem) that $\mathcal{E}$ is uniformly dense in $\mathcal{C}(G)$, the algebra of continuous functions on $G$. This follows from the Gelfand-Raikov theorem and the Stone-Weierstrass theorem. In that sense, Gelfand-Raikov determines $\mathcal{C}(G)$ and hence $G$.

In terms of the theory, Peter-Weyl then gives you a decomposition of $L^2(G)$ as 
$$L^2(G) = \bigoplus_{[\pi]} \mathcal{E}_\pi$$
which is the start of much of Fourier analysis on groups.